# Format number in userform textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a texbox in a userform in which the user will input numbers. Those numbers will be tranfered to an Excel spreadsheet for calculation.

I want that when the user inputs numbers in the Textbox it displays as a number in a specific format.

For example: 2000000, I want it as 2,000,000.00 in the Textbox.

I tried:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()    
    TextBox1 = Format(TextBox1, "$#,##0.00")
End Sub
```

But the Userform doesn't change.

If I try the following

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    TextBox1 = Format(TextBox1, "$#,##0.00")
End Sub
```

The userform shows the number adequately, but then updates the Excel spreadsheet with a text format instead of number and the calculation doesn't run.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround, use the second subroutine to get the value in a string format.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    TextBox1 = Format(TextBox1, "$#,##0.00")
End Sub
```

Then convert the format of the cell where this value was assigned.
`Range("A1").Value = CDbl(Range("A1").Value)`

Comment: Use _Exit() event instead as _Change() prevents full entry of number with decimals because it tries to reformat the full number as you type, though you haven't finished entering it. _Exit worked perfectly, though.

Answer (score 2):

Double click on textbox and then 
You should use AfterUpdate event

```
Private Sub txtmoney_AfterUpdate()
Me.txtmoney.Value = Format(Me.txtmoney.Value, "$#,##0.00")

End Sub
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a programmatic solution, not a manual one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the exit event to format, as change event tries to reformat as you type and may not allow you to even enter the whole number.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    TextBox1 = Format(TextBox1, "$#,##0.00")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it writing this:

```
Range("A1").value = textbox1.value
```

instead of this

```
Range("A1").value = textbox1
```

In my case the `.value` made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Just format the destination columns to the number format, you won't have to bother wih the text box..